# What is the formula for finding the center of gravity of this strange shape.

Tags: geometry, 3d

Given the values of $R$, $H$, and $X$(second picture). Is there a formula for finding the center of gravity of this three dimensional shape?

[image: this is the shape]

Here is a diagram of its cross section (the actual cross section is the dark blue. the rest is just there to clarify).
Notice the sphere making the indent (light blue) has the same radius as the original sphere (dark blue).

[image: diagram of cross section]

Comment: Could you please say what tools you have available? Particularly (if this came from a class you're taking), have you calculated any centers of mass, and if so, how? Have you tried anything for this object, and if so, what didn't work?

Comment: This isn't home work its completely out of curiosity. So you can use any tools you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The center of gravity of two bodies is the weighted mean of the centers of each. Of course the weights is the weight (mass) of each body.
Moreover the center is on the  symmetry axis (axes).
In your case, since the density of the body is supposed constant, we can use volume as weight.
Since the volume of the double [Spherical Cap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap) is
$$ V = 2\,\pi \frac{{H^{\,2} }}{3}\left( {3R - H} \right)$$
then, measuring the CG position along the symmetry axis, with the $0$ placed at the center of the sphere, and oriented towards the cavity, we will have
$$
0 = \text{Cg}_{\,\text{whole}\,\text{sphere}}  = \frac{{V_{\,\text{hollow}\,\text{sphere}} \text{Cg}_{\,\text{hollow}\,\text{sphere}}  + V_{\,\text{double}\,\text{cap}} \text{Cg}_{\,\text{double}\,\text{cap}} }}
{{V_{\,\text{whole}\,\text{sphere}} }}
$$
i.e.
\begin{gathered}
  \text{Cg}_{\,\text{hollow}\,\text{sphere}}  =  - \frac{{V_{\,\text{double}\,\text{cap}} }}
{{\left( {V_{\,\text{whole}\,\text{sphere}}  - V_{\,\text{double}\,\text{cap}} } \right)}}\text{Cg}_{\,\text{double}\,\text{cap}}  =  \hfill \\
   =  - \frac{{2\,\pi \frac{{H^{\,2} }}
{3}\left( {3R - H} \right)}}
{{\left( {4\,\pi \frac{{R^{\,3} }}
{3} - 2\,\pi \frac{{H^{\,2} }}
{3}\left( {3R - H} \right)} \right)}}\left( {R - H} \right) =  \hfill \\
   =  - \frac{{\,\left( {R - H} \right)}}
{{\left( {2\,\frac{{R^{\,3} }}
{{H^{\,2} \left( {3R - H} \right)}} - \,1} \right)}} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}